# Android Creating Horizontal scroll view of Images for Image Picker

Tags: android, imageview, swipe, gesture

I would like to create an image picker as shown in the picture below. What is the best way to go about it?

The screen should show the current image on the center and the next and previous on its side which is a smaller image size. On swipe, the images should change. It will be helpful if someone can point to an existing code similar to this.

Thanks

[image]